# How to rollback the changes when there is error in promise chain

Tags: lightning-aura-components

how to rollback the changes when there is error in promise chain.

for example: promise has 3 methods

- verifytheValue
- savetheRequest
- sendToAws

> In savetheRequest method we are sending email to few users. we cant bring that logic to sendToAwsMethod.

So whats happening here :

**In sendToAws method is failing but still Email is triggering to particular Users.
If all 3 method is successfully. then only mail should trigger. How to do this??**

send email logic in Apex side. Please let me know if these Information are not enough to answer the question.I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't roll back a transaction once completed. In your case, you may want to simply change the order of execution (verify, send to aws, then email). Or, if possible, just write a fourth method that calls each of the other three in succession so you can do it all at once, if possible.

Comment: this way not possible in my case : verify, send to aws, then email. ill write fourth method and try it. thanks sfdcfox

Comment: but how to check all 3 methods got success in javascript promise

Comment: @AnnappaPH `Promise.all([method1(),method2(),method3()]).then(result=>{...}).catch(error=>{...})`

Comment: got it. Thanks..